# Determine if a document is read only when opened from a link

Tags: vba, ms-word

If I open a Word document through Word which someone else has open, it will open as read only and the property `doc.readOnly = True`.

If I do the same through a hyperlink from Chrome, Excel, Outlook, etc. the document shows as read only in Word but the property `doc.readOnly = False`.

This makes my code dependent on how you open the document.

How can I determine if a document is read only when opened from a link? It should only trigger if someone else has it open, if you have it open all is fine.

```
' *****************************************************************************
' **************** ONLY works for document that is not read only     **********
' *****************************************************************************

If doc.readOnly = True Then 'Or FileHandling.whoHasFileOpen(doc) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You are not allowed to do changes on a read only document with our macro")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Which version of Word and which version of Windows are involved, here? That could be important for repro-testing. Right off-hand, though, would it help if you could test for the presence of "Read-only" in the application title bar?

Comment: I am using word 2016 on a windows 7 desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the title bar caption this can be solved:

```
' *********************************************************************************************
' ************************ ONLY works for document that is not read only **********************
' *********************************************************************************************

If doc.readOnly = True Or InStr(UCase(doc.ActiveWindow.Caption), "READ-ONLY") > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("You are not allowed to do changes on a read only document with our macro")
    Exit Sub
End If
```